# What parameters to use with android inflater

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I have created a listview using an online tutorial where I am trying to create a multicolumned listview. All tutorials have told me I need an inflater but none show what to put or should be in the corresponding xml file. Could anyone please shed some light on this.

I'm setting the listview in the oncreate method. I have the following method with an inflater:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But there is nothing in the menu_main.xml file.

Because it's multicolumned I have the listview in the main xml file like follows:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/currentChores">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/choreList"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currentChores"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">
</ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And then I made a seperate xml file for the columns called chore_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chore_name"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chore"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Child"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/point_value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Points"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"   />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm trying to create this list view using the following line:

```
mySimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(Chores.this, chores, R.layout.chore_list, new String[]{"chore","child_name","points"},new int[]{R.id.chore_name,R.id.child_name,R.id.point_value });
list.setAdapter(mySimpleAdapter);
```

When I run this I can scroll further down the page which is telling me there is something there but I can't see anything

Comment: questions seems little confusing try to make it more clear

Comment: Seems like you are a beginner buddy :) onCreateOptionsMenu is where you inflate menu view :) onCreate is where you load lists view :) So if you are thinking how is my listview is being displayed when there is nothing in menu_main.xml thats because you are looking at wrong method :) If you see carefully onCreate method you must be having something like setContentView(R.layout.main); if you open up main_activity.xml you will see listview in that :) As per why there is nothing in menu_main.xml?? it is the code that u'll see by default when you create a instance of Activity class

Comment: menu_main.xml as name suggests it is the menu for main activity :) Have you seen three vertical dots to the top right hand corner of the device or bottom right corner of the device??? when you tap on it a list of options appears in some apps??? That is nothing but menu options :) So if you also want to provide a menu with options like that you have to declare those options in menu_main. Because android does not know what you want it is keeping it empty buddy :)

Comment: Now how to write my own menu??? Its simple many of them have already answered that below :) anyway if you want to learn how to do it I prefer you read one of the online tutorials if you need readily one see this, http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/ This will not only teach you how to load menu but also teaches u how to handle when user taps on one of the options in menu :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The method `onCreateOptionsMenu` is used to inflate menu,not ListView.If you want to custom views of each row for your ListView,you should create a Adapter class which extends `BaseAdapter` and implement its `getView` method,and in this method inflate your custom xml layout for you view of each row.

There is a article about this:https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html.

**EDIT:After looking at your newest question,I think your problem is because your data source has no data,that means `chores` is empty.When you create a `SimpleAdapter`,the second parameter is your data source,and its key must corresponding to the string array behind this parameter.**

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code creates Menu not a ListView

Menus info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

ListView info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

**onCreateOptionsMenu** method :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And `your item in corresponding xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Menu

> Defines a Menu, which is a container for menu items. A <menu> element
>   must be the root node for the file and can hold one or more <item> and
>   <group> elements.

Item

> Creates a MenuItem, which represents a single item in a menu. This
>   element may contain a nested <menu> element in order to create a
>   submenu.

Group

> An optional, invisible container for <item> elements. It allows you to
>   categorize menu items so they share properties such as active state
>   and visibility. For more information, see the section about Creating
>   Menu Groups.

Please visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inflater like this

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;

inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```